# Flutter Riverpod - how to have another provider change the state on a provider without forcing a

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Is it possible to have a RiverPod provider listen to a change from a secondary provider without having a rebuild of the main provider?

The usual pattern for listening to other providers is like...

```
final providerA = StateNotifierProvider<NotifierA,ModelA>( (ref) {
   final aModelB = ref.watch(providerB)
   final aModelA = ModelA();
   aModelA.someProp = aModelB.someProp;
   return NotifierA(ModelA);
});
```

However,  I want to listen to changes in provider B and keep the current state of provider A.  Is this possible?

```
final providerA = StateNotifierProvider<NotifierA,ModelA>( (ref) {    
   final aModelB = ref.watch(providerB)  // react to change in other provider
   final aModelA = ref.read(providerA);  // get the current state of provider A
   aModelA.someProp = aModelB.someProp;
   return NotifierA(ModelA);
});
```

In other words, I don't want to lose the current state of providerA when I react to an incoming change from provider B.

Comment: If you want a partial update of state, use ref.listen instead of watch.